# Unable to replace manually installed video driver with proprietary Nvidia driver in 22.04LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia

My setup includes an EVGA Nvidia 1080 video card on an EVGA X99 Classified MB. When I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 it seems that the upgrade changed the proprietary Nvidia driver to the open source Nvidia driver. The open source driver doesn't work well in either the "Wayland" or "Ubuntu" Gnome desktop login options.

My perusal of similar questions here referring to earlier version of Ubuntu with NVIDIA issues hasn't answered my problem.

I want to install the proprietary Nvidia driver, but 22.04 refuses to let me select that option. Here is a screenshot of what I see:
[image]

I can not uncheck the manually installed driver (which I never manually installed) and select the proprietary driver that the OS acknowledges is available.
Thanks for any help in fixing this.

Comment: For a long shot `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this qualifies as an "answer" which will help anyone other than myself. But, since posting my question, it seems the Ubuntu gods sent down an update from on high:

[image]

The update advised that because there was a problem with my system, I needed to performed a "partial upgrade" as directed. After the partial upgrade I was able to install the Nvidia proprietary driver.